# Average number of posts written by user in R

Tags: r, text, average, tapply

I have a dataframe with text and user_type. I want to get the average number of posts written by user_type.

**Data:**

```
df$post
[1] "hi my name is"
[2] "hey how are you"
[3] "whats up"

df$user_type

[1] big_user
[2] big_user
[3] small_user
```

Comment: What is "the average number of texts"? The average length of the texts?

Comment: The count of the texts, so here, for example, big_user has written 2 posts, and small_user only one. I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
# counting the posts per user
df %>%
  count(user_type)
#    user_type n
# 1   big_user 2
# 2 small_user 1

# calculating the average length of posts per user
df %>% 
  group_by(user_type) %>%
  summarise(average = sum(str_count(text))/n(), .groups="drop")
#   A tibble: 2 x 2
#   user_type  average
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 big_user        14
# 2 small_user       8
```

Using `base R`:

```r
table(df$user_type)
#   big_user small_user 
#          2          1
```

Comment: Does this give the average?

Comment: What exactly do you meen with "average"? "Average" per what?

Comment: Average number of posts per user type

Comment: The average doesn't make sense here, since you always end up with average = (sum of terms) / (number of terms), which in your case are the same so the average will alwys be one

Comment: As @DominikS.Meier pointed out, your request is problematic. We could calculate the average number of posts per day, in this case we need additional information about the posting date. We could calculate the average length of posts per user. But "the average number of posts per user" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay, thanks! How could I calculate the average length of posts per users?